# Invariant and Tchebytchev polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

it's related to an invariant in fact I would like to solve this :

> Let $x,y$ be real positive numbers such that :
>   $$x^n-y^n=1$$

My question is :

What's the functions such that :

$$g(z)^n+h(z)^n=1$$

It's well-know that we have :

$$ch(x)^2-sh(x)^2=1$$

And a little bit more curious we have :

$$[T_n(\frac{x+x^{-1}}{2})]^2-(\frac{x+x^{-1}}{2})^2[U_{n-1}(\frac{x+x^{-1}}{2})]^2=1$$

With $T_n$ is the [polynomials (of the first kind) of Tchebytchev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) and $U_n$ the second .

But I have no idea for the other cases . Maybe the polynomials of Tchebytchev are the solution ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which type of functions are you requiring the solutions to be, polynomials?

Comment: Chebyshev or Čebyšëv are better translitterations.